# Background Audio is enabled but not needed

Tags: audiokit, background-audio

following the examples, I enabled the Background Audio capability in my app, even though I do not need it. I want simple playback only, with midi triggering sounds (sf2) from the app bundle only, in foreground only. I got everything working and submitted my first version to the App Store and I get complaints from the reviewer saying that if I don't use background audio (so they can't test it) then I should switch it off in the Capabilities. If I do that my foreground audio triggering stops working. Can anyone help in what is the proper way configure AKSettings and the app in this case, so I could pass the app store review?